# Display page length and pagination in the same line jquery dataTables

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Is there any way to display the page-length option and paginate option in the same line? This is how I got:

[image]

Is there any way to override their css and display them in the same line? They both are in two separate div. I've added "jquery.dataTables.min.css" and "bootstrap.min.css".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom#Styling) option to construct the layout for Bootstrap framework.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8'p>>"
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zg1ornb8/1/) for code and demonstration

Comment: This is working and awesome. How can you place the info in between them??

Answer (score 6):

edit: Ah, I realized I can't reply to a comments in comment, I hope the OP can sees this.

simply add the character i for information

as example, if you want to have i after l, then put as below

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-4'li><'col-sm-8'p>>"
});
```

else you can even let i have it's own col-sm, as follows (note that I decreases pagination, p from 8 to 4 in order to fit into 12 division of 'row' by bootstrap standard.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-4'i><'col-sm-4'p>>"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

on bootstrap 4  I  overide  by 
"language": {
                "sProcessing": "กำลังดำเนินการ...",
                "sLengthMenu": "แสดง_MENU_ แถว",
                "sZeroRecords": "ไม่พบข้อมูล",
                "sInfo": "แสดง *START* ถึง *END* จาก *TOTAL* แถว",
                "sInfoEmpty": "แสดง 0 ถึง 0 จาก 0 แถว",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(กรองข้อมูล *MAX* ทุกแถว)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sSearch": "ค้นหา:",
                "sUrl": "",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "เิริ่มต้น",
                    "sPrevious": "ก่อนหน้า",
                    "sNext": "ถัดไป",
                    "sLast": "สุดท้าย"
                }
            },

Answer (score 0):

Just override Datatable CSS class `.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length` by adding new property as per below.

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i've tried to achieve length,info and paginate at the bottom of the table. You can see the result below.

[image: Datatable length,info,paginate same line]

To achieve this, first you should set [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) property of your DataTable.

```
dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-3'i><'col-sm-6'p>>"
```

After that put and customize the code below for your own needs, in your **CSS** file or between the **<style>** tags.

```
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_info {
    padding-top: 1.7em;
}
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_length {
    padding-top: 0.3em;
}
```

This solved my problem. But in case you need to style other properties of datatable, you are free to use the selectors below.

```
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_filter {
    padding-top: 0.8em;
}
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_paginate {
    padding-top: 0.8em;
}
```